# removing objects from array

Tags: javascript

i have an `array = []` and it contains objects... `obj, obj, obj`. I have to remove `obj two`, but i don't know the index... so how can i remove obj. the name of the object is also same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope it helps you:

```
function removeByElement(array,obj) {
  for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++ ) { 
    if(array[i]==obj) {
      array.splice(i,1); 
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

EDIT:
 breaking the loop.

Comment: oh, and it'll fail if you have two or more consecutive matching elements.

Comment: This is a bad approach. If you delete an item, then you'll skip over the next one at `i++`. Either break once you've deleted an item, or traverse the array in reverse order.

Answer (score 5):

The ES5 way to do this is with [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
 myarray = myarray.filter(function(val, index, a) {
    return (val !== obj);
 });
```

See the MDN page linked above for a version to use if you don't have ES5.

Technically this creates a new array, rather than modify the original array.  However `splice` as proposed in other answers isn't particularly efficient anyway since it has to renumber all of the indices above each matching element, and will do so over and over if there's more than one match.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeObject(obj, arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === obj) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do not know the index, you have to iterate on all elements and check each if they are the one you look for, and then `delete` it.

```
var len = your_array.length;
for(var i=0; i<len;i++){
  if(typeof(your_arry[i])=='classOfTypeYouLookFor'){// OR if(your_array[i].property_of_class && your_array[i].property_of_class==some_specific_value){
      delete(your_arry[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will leave behind a hole in the array

Comment: might be I misunderstood the question